# R help in subsetting daily range with POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I am trying to subset an interval inside of each day of a POSIXct time series.

Suppose I have a sample set of 3 days, sampled every 15 minutes.

```
sample <- seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00"),as.POSIXct("2000-01-03 24:00:00"),by=15*60)

 [1] "2000-01-01 00:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 00:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 00:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 00:45:00 PST" "2000-01-01 01:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 01:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 01:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 01:45:00 PST"
 [9] "2000-01-01 02:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 02:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 02:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 02:45:00 PST" "2000-01-01 03:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 03:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 03:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 03:45:00 PST"
[17] "2000-01-01 04:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 04:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 04:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 04:45:00 PST"
```

Using the lubridate package, I could subset by an hourly interval fairly easily.

```
sample_subset <- sample[hour(sample) >= 9 & hour(sample) =< 12]

 [1] "2000-01-01 10:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 10:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 10:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 10:45:00 PST" "2000-01-01 11:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 11:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 11:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 11:45:00 PST"
"2000-01-02 10:00:00 PST" "2000-01-02 10:15:00 PST" "2000-01-02 10:30:00 PST" "2000-01-02 10:45:00 PST" "2000-01-02 11:00:00 PST" "2000-01-02 11:15:00 PST" "2000-01-02 11:30:00 PST" "2000-01-02 11:45:00 PST"
```

The problem comes on how to subset a fixed hourly/minute interval inside of each day. I want to subset from 9:30
to 12:00 each day.  If I just add a filter, such as minute(sample) > 30, it would filter out minutes for every single hour in the range.

I looked at several related posts; but they only show hourly filtering. It seems like there should be a fairly simple subset condition I am not understanding. Something like sample[minute(sample)[hour(sample)==9] >30] That doesn't work, though. Any other simple ideas?

*edit

based on ilister's idea I simply extended boolean indexing with lubridate.
I somehow missed the ORing.

```
cond1 <-  hour(sample) >= 9 & minute(sample) > 30

cond2 <-  hour(sample) < 12

cond3 <-  hour(sample) > 9

       sample[(cond1 | cond3) & cond2] 

       "2000-01-01 09:45:00 PST" "2000-01-01 10:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 10:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01 10:30:00 PST" "2000-01-01 10:45:00 PST"
   "2000-01-01 11:00:00 PST" "2000-01-01 11:15:00 PST" "2000-01-01
   11:30:00 PST"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try subsetting with joint conditions from indexClass {xts}:

```
require(xts)
sample <- seq(as.POSIXct("2000-01-01 00:00:00"),
              as.POSIXct("2000-01-03 24:00:00"),by=15*60)
xsample <- xts(1:289, order.by=sample)
xsample[.indexhour(xsample)==9 & .indexmin(xsample) %in% 15:59]
```

Would return results in the set 9:15 to <10:00.

And then join that indexing with a standard .indexhour to return the set 10:00 to 12:00.

```
xsample[c(which(.indexhour(xsample)==9 & .indexmin(xsample) %in% 15:59),
          which(.indexhour(xsample) %in% 10:11))]
```

Or if you are comfortable with boolean operators, more elegantly:

```
xsample[.indexhour(xsample)==9 & .indexmin(xsample) %in% 15:59 |
        .indexhour(xsample) %in% 10:11]
```

Comment: Seeing the expected results in the question, why not `xsample["T09:30:00/T11:59:59"]`?

Answer (score 0):

In base R, the `POSIXlt` might be useful. Try this:

```
    sampleLT<-as.POSIXlt(sample)
    secFromMidnigth<-sampleLT$hour*3600+sampleLT$min*60+sampleLT$sec
    sample[secFromMidnigth>9*3600+30*60 & secFromMidnigth<3600*12]
```

You can extract the number of seconds from midnight of a given datetime and see if it is bigger than 9*3600+30*60 (the 09:30) and lower of 3600*12 (the 12:00).

I don't know much of `lubridate` but as I can see from your OP you can do the same:

```
    sample[hour(sample)*60+minute(sample)>9*60+30 & hour(sample)<12]
```